# Google+ Moments:Insert AddActivity generic error

Tags: c#, rest, google-plus

I'm trying to publish an app moment for Google+. The app successfully completes the authentication process and receives the access token. The problem happens when I try to call the Moment.Insert API on "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault", always returns this unspecified error message

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

The API steps I'm following are the ones listed here https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert and the request looks like this

```
{
 "target": {
  "kind": "plus#itemScope",
  "name": "Sample Test for Google Plus REST API",
  "id": "88370F18-81A4-47F5-BC2F-19EDBE326A20",
  "url": "http://schema.org/Thing"
 },
 "type": "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
 "kind": "plus#moment"
}
```

I also add the access token to the request header & the api key to the url as a parameter.

I don't know if I'm missing something here but it may worth saying that I receive the exact same error message when using the API explorer in Google Dev. Console.

Thanks in advance for any insights

Comment: I posted the version of code that worked with me. hope it would help you.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I am getting unauthorized error. I am posting my code in Answers, I can't post whole code in comments. It's too big. Can you please post your full code. I will appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: I updated the code below to include the full REST operation code using RestSharp library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the moment declaration that worked for me. For some reason, the description field is required and not adding it would produce this strange error message.

```
var client = new RestClient();

var moment = new
{
    kind = "plus#moment",
    type = "https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
    target = new
    {
        kind = "plus#itemScope",
        id = "GENERATE-A-POST-ID-HERE",
        type = "https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
        name = "SOMTHING-TO-POST",
        description = "SOMTHING-TO-POST"
    }
};

var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("{0}?key={1}", GOOGLE_POST_URL, GOOGLE_APP_ID), Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("authorization", "BEARER-ACCESS-TOKEN-RECEIVED-BEFORE");
request.AddBody(moment);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, OnPostCompleted);
```

I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) library to handle the REST operations.

Hope this would help.